# How to specify the dbpath in mango configuration file

Tags: mongodb

I have a Grails application with MongoDB as database, each time that I run my app I have to go to Command Prompt and define dbPath otherwise Test connection will fail. In MongoDB documentation I read that dpPath can be specified in configuration file, but I can not figure it out how I am supposed to do it. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create mongo.config file..

> dbpath=D:\mongodb\your path
>
> logpath=D:\mongodb\log\mongo.log
>
> bind_ip=127.0.0.1
>
> port=3979

then start the mongod as

> mongod --config D:\mongodb\mongo.config